# Enable SLP in Yosemite 10.10?

Tags: osx-yosemite, slp

SLP worked fine in 10.6/7/8/9, but seems disabled by default in 10.10 (enhanced security?).

How do I enable SLP in 10.10?  I don't see it in Directory Utility.app.  Is there an API to enable SLP?  My app has been using the open source SLP package with no problems in 10.6/7/8/9, but it gets no response from servers in 10.10; there are no error returns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed during 10.10.2 development, found to be working again in build 14C109.  It was a more general problem of some (carbon?) events being dropped.